# Render page with backend data to be used in getInitialProps in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm new to next.js. What I need to achieve in my next.js project is to connect to database, get some data, handle it with express and use it on the client side of my app. I will connect to DB within express route handlers. The question: is it possible to pass dowloaded data to client side (ie. to `getInitialProps` lifecycle method) without fetching it (with for.ex.`fetch` api) from within `getInitialProps`, ie. is there a way to have it already ready to consume on the client side via some props (without classical fetching method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch your data with express with something similar to this, in express:

```
server.get('/your/route', async (req, res) => {
  // fetch your data
  let data = await fetch(....)
  return app.render(req, res, '/yourpage',data)
})
```

And then in `getInitialProps` you can access your  data:

```
   static async getInitialProps (context) {
     let data = context.query;
     return {data}
   }
```